# Conditionally keep Rows in Selection

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I need help with an SQL query. The following table is a result of several joined tables and filtered by some columns. It is now in a (hopefully correct) simplified state.

```
----------------------
|  A |  B  | C |  D  |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 651 | n | 656 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 651 | j | 658 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 804 | n | 659 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 651 | n | 660 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 512 | j | 660 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 670 | j | 660 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 512 | n | 668 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 651 | n | 668 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 670 | n | 668 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 651 | n | 414 |
----------------------
```

I now need to further define the result.

- Have only one row per value in D
- If there is one where `C='j'` take one of these.

The new result should look like this:

```
----------------------
|  A |  B  | C |  D  |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 651 | n | 656 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 651 | j | 658 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 804 | n | 659 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 512 | j | 660 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 512 | n | 668 |
|----+-----+---+-----|
| 81 | 651 | n | 414 |
----------------------
```

As can be seen for `D='660'` there are two rows with `C='j'`. I took the first of them.

For `D='668'` there is no row with `C='j'`. So I don't care which one should stay. I took the first of them.

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
;with cte as
(select a,b,c,d, row_number() over (partition by d order by c,b) rn
 from your_derived_resultset)
select a,b,c,d 
from cte
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I think, it should be `order by c, b`. OP wants C=j values on priority.

Comment: `b,c` is working as is `c,b`. But I agree with your interpretation, and will update my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query my friend:

```
with t1 as
(select * from table1 where D not in
(select D from table1 where c = 'j')
union all
select * from table1 where D in
(select D from table1 where c = 'j')
and c = 'j')
select a,min(b) b,c,d from t1 group by a,c,d;
```

### [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d75b3/8)

Answer (score 0):

```
with t (A,B,C,D)
as
(
select 81,512,'j',660 from dual
union
select 81,670,'j',660 from dual
union 
select 81,651,'n',668 from dual
union
select 81,670,'n',668 from dual
)
select * from 
(
select A,B,C,D,row_number() over (partition by D order by B) as roww
from t
) 
where roww=1
```

This works as well,.